# Cannot resolve method 'getName' in 'Optional'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to get the value of my database with the getter `getName()`.
First, I have created User.java:

```
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    private String dob;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

Then I have created UserRepository.java:

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.repository;

import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

And this is my service where I try to get the value of `getName()`:

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.service;

import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity.User;
import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<User> getUser() {
        return userRepository.findById(1).getName();
    }
}
```

But I get the error *Cannot resolve method 'getName' in 'Optional'*. Why?

Comment: Which part of the error don't you understand? `Optional` doesn't have a `getName` method. And your `userRepository.findById(1)` call returns an `Optional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you should change your method implementation like:

```java
public Optional<String> getUser() {
    return userRepository.findById(1)
                         .map(User::getName);
}
```

Comment: That helped me. Thank you!